# Jquery - Fit text into element with only letterspacing & word-spacing

Tags: jquery, font-size, justify, letter-spacing, word-spacing

Is there a plugin for this? I have been screening of the internetz and found bigText, Justify, fitText, textFit but they all seem to work with the font-size which I dont want to do. I only want the text to fit inside a element with a defined width.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="title">
   <h1>One header that i pretty long</h1>
   <h2>Sub-header that is shorter</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#title {
   width: 300px;
}

h1 {
   font-size: 3em;
}

h2 {
   font-size: 2em;
}
```

The problem with the plugins that I've found so far is that the sub-header will be bigger in the end because it has a shorter amount of letters.

I've found this solution but the problem is that it gives me a slightly unbalanced spacing, [justify](http://www.quora.com/Web-Development/How-to-justify-a-single-word-by-changing-letter-spacing-using-JQuery)

**JS**

```
if(config.fonts_loaded){
            $(".title .justify").each(function(i, e) {
            var $t    = $(this);
            console.log($t.height());
            var text  = $t.text();
            var tLen  = text.length -1;
            var i     = 0;
            var letter;
            var ratio;
            //  We have the data we need to rebuild text. Lose original text.
            //
            $t.empty();
            while(i <= tLen) {
              letter = $("<span></span>")
              .css({
                "position" : "absolute"
              })
              .text(text.charAt(i));
              $t.append(letter);
              ratio = i / tLen;
              //  Place each character in its rational slot, retreating margin

              //  so as to stay within bounds (last character starts at 100% of width).

              //

              letter.css({

                "left"      : (100 * ratio) + "%",

                "margin-left" : -letter.width() * ratio

              });

              ++i

            }

          });
        }
```

Results in:
  [image]

Comment: Please put things like this in a jsFiddle, but otherwise it looks fine to me here: http://jsfiddle.net/w6DJW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a script myself instead and started with lettering to separate each letter from each other and then work out how much space they took together.

[Lettering.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js)

This is my final code,

```
function letter_space_me(element){
    var el = $(element).text();
    el = el.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;'); // REPLACE ALL WHITESPACES WITH &NBSP;
    $(element).html(el);
    $(element).lettering();
    var characters = $(element + ' span');
    var number_of_chars = characters.length;
    var parent_width = $(element).parent().width()

    var total_width = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        total_width += $(characters[i]).width();
    };

    var spacing = (parent_width - total_width) / (number_of_chars - 1); // GET SPACING PER CHARACTERS EXCEPT FOR THE LAST CHARACTER WHICH WE DONT WANT TO GIVE AND SPACE TO.

    for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        if((characters.length - i) > 1){
            $(characters[i]).css({'padding-right' : spacing + 'px'});
        }
    };
}
```